# How to add tooltip in twism jQuery map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using: [twism jquery map](https://github.com/cody1213/twism).

I want to add tool-tip on hover of the country.

```
 <div id="worldmap"></div>

   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#worldmap').twism("create", 
        {
          map: "world",
          border: "red",
          disableCountries: ['ar'],
          individualCountrySettings: [{
            name: "cn",
            color: "red"
          }]
        }, function() {
          //callback function after map loads
          $('#worldmap').twism("setCountry", {
            name: "ca",
            color: "blue",
            hoverColor: "yellow",
            hoverBorder: "purple",
            hover: function(state) {
              alert("You clicked "+state);

            },

          });
        });
      });
```

On hover it alerts the state but I want to show the tool-tip.